# How to print the two digit numbers from 1 to 100 in java?

Tags: java

I don't know the exact logic, just tried as below. Looking for easy & simple logic to print the two digit numbers from 1 to 100 using java

```
public class TwoDigitNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = 2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");// will give the number as 100
        int num = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

            System.out.println(i);
            while (num>0) {
              num=num/10;
            count = count + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-math-random-method-examples/  try this

Comment: Do you specifically need to count digits for arbitrary input? The far easier way is just to loop from 10 to 99.

Comment: Git. Join on me.

Comment: Either the answer is trivial (`for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) { System.out.println(i); }` ) or it is unclear what you are really asking.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below simple logic to print 2 digits numbers from 1-100

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count = 2;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the number");// will give the number as 100
            int num = input.nextInt();
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                if (i % 10 > 0 && i % 10 < 10) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait I don't understand if you just want to print the two digits numbers from 1 to 100 using "easy and simple logic" why couldn't you just:

```
System.out.print("Printing two digit numbers from 1 to 100: ");
for(int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) {
  System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
System.out.println("");
```

Output => Printing two digit numbers from 1 to 100: 10, 11, 12, ... , 99